# Opened ports for socket connection. Is it safe?

Tags: security, sockets, ports

In my VPS I have 2 ports opened to listen incoming socket connection from gps tracking devices.
I would like to know the security risks if any, and what are the prevention that need to be done. My customers know the IP address and Port number.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see it, the security is not a problem, as long as you accept connections from well known clients. A packet header with some indicators at the begging of the conversation with a random generated password (based on time/date for example) would be enough to acknowledge the client.

At the firewall you should allow those ports to get through.

Also, if the interchanged data is confidential consider encrypting it to avoid someone sniff the data.

There is also a problem if someone wants to open a lot of connections simultaneously, at the server allows a reasonably numbers of open connections at a time, so that the server won't get exhausted.

Comment: ja_mesa, A good suggestion to limit the number of simultaneous connection. This question came up to my mind as, security advisers always ask not to keep opened ports.  But here I have to open ports to listen. I can make sure to sanitize received data.  So isn't any other security risk through this port?

Comment: As I said, I don't see any risk; if you are listening at a port for connections you decide who can communicate with you. Also, you may implement a list of well known clients and only permit those clients to connect. When a client wants to transmit data it needs to sign in first. There are different techniques for this scenario. Security advisors says not to keep ports opened, except, of course, those that are under your control. That's how you keep Trojans away.

Answer (score 0):

> "I would like to know the security risks if any"

There are ALWAYS security risks when transmitting data.

> "and what are the prevention that need to be done"

Implementing a strong encryption algorithm, like [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) will secure your data from snooping. Alternatively, you can implement an Assymetric encryption scheme like [RSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29). This will mean that everyone encrypts data with your `public key`, and only you can read it with your `private key`.

Finally, implementing a hashing algorithm to act as a `checksum` might be beneficial to ensuring the integrity of your information. Using an algorithm like [sha1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) is considered the standard, although it is a growing opinion that we need to move to stronger algorithms, like the [sha-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) family of ciphers.

**How all of these things can work together**

Using all of these things in conjunction with one another is called [Secure Sockets Layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Sockets_Layer). Read up on this algorithm, and find out if there is a native implementation in your chosen language. A fully working implementation of `SSL` can assure you that the message is coming from the correct person and the message hasn't been tampered with.

Comment: Chris, thanks for you prompt reply. My concern is not securing transmitted data (I sanitize my data before handling.), but possible security threat to my server, that someone might access through the opened port.

Comment: In what way? Some form of SQL Injection? Please be more specific.